# PhantomJS isn't saving cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

I'm running the latest version of PhantomJS on Windows 8.1. Here's my code:

```
console.log('cookies: ',phantom.cookies);

phantom.addCookie({
    domain:'google.com',
    path:'/',
    expires:(new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60),
    name:'test',
    value:'value'
});

phantom.exit();
```

And I tried calling it like this:

```
phantomjs test.js --cookies-file=cookies.txt
```

and

```
phantomjs test.js --cookies-file="C:\path\cookies.txt"
```

Either way, `cookies.txt` isn't being created and `phantom.cookies` is empty. How do I make PhantomJS save cookies?

Comment: PhantomJS has a different execution environment than node. There are bridges between PhantomJS and node.js, but this script does not use such a bridge.

Answer (score 2):

`--cookies-file` is supposed to be an option for PhantomJS and not for your script. PhantomJS also supports passing commandline arguments to the script. You need to flip the order:

```
phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt test.js
```

When you execute this line once, `phantom.cookies` will be empty, but cookies.txt will be created with a single entry. Only when you execute it a second time you will see that `phantom.cookies` isn't empty.

The cookie jar is read before your script starts and written after you exit your script.